# Динамическое добавление вложенных переменных в существующую структуру переменных

Tags: ansible

Есть структура вида в котором хранятся объекты со своими какими-то свойствами, которые прописаны в файле определения переменных:

`vars:
  objects:
    - name: objectA:
      sectionB:
        property1: "value1"
        property2: "value2"
        property3: "value3"`

Хотел бы динамически во время исполнения моего playbook исполнять task, который добавлял бы в данный(ые) объект(ы) дополнительное динамически вычисляемое свойство.

Нашел много примеров, которые динамически добавляют элементы (items) в словарь (dictionary), но вот подобного найти не получается.

Требуется сделать нечто подобное (один из вариантов, которые я пробовал использовать):

`- set_fact:
    item.sectionB: "{{item.sectionB | combine(property_string) }}"
  with_items:
    - "{{ objects }}"
  vars:
    property_string: '{ property4: "value4" }'`

Чтобы получить в итоге:

`vars:
  objects:
    - name: objectA:
      sectionB:
        property1: value1
        property2: value2
        property3: value3
        property4: value4`

Пробовал использовать функцию combine(), она в таком виде отрабатывает без ошибок, но структуру не изменяет, а функция union() завершается ошибкой.

Comment: метки в заголовках не нужны: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/607/213987

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот здесь описан принцип решения: https://ansibledaily.com/process-complex-variables-with-set_fact-and-with_items/

Изменить изначальную переменную нельзя, но можно при помощи `set_fact` сделать факт с таким же именем, который в большинстве случаев будет меть приоритет к изначальной переменной.

Первым шагом формируете новый список объектов с добавлением к элементам нужных атрибутов через `combine`. Примерно:

```
- set_fact:
    tmp_object: "{{ item | combine(<объет_с_дополнениям>) }}"
  with_items: "{{ objects }}"
  register: tmp_objects
```

И потом из `tmp_objects` достаем то, что нам на самом деле нужно:

```
- set_fact:
    objects: {{ tmp_objects.results | map(attribute='ansible_facts.tmp_object') | list }}"
```

Comment: Воспользовался этим советом, сделав по своему.
Пришел к выводу, что динамическое пост-добавление данных в существующую структуру невозможно
Спасибо, Константин, за ваш ответ!